# Android - Add screens and swipe through them

Tags: java, android, swipe

TL;DR version:
I want to add multiple instances of the same activity in my app and swipe through them.

---

I'm creating a home replacement app and I would like to know how to set up multiple home screens. I checked out the sample app provided in the SDK but it has only one screen.

I have almost everything set up but now realised that I couldn't figure out how to add multiple home screens and swipe through them. I'm just guessing that since the home screen is an activity, launchers add the same activity multiple times and let the user swipe through them. Is this correct?

What I can't figure out is how it does so and how it lets the user select the number of screens he/she wants and add/remove those activities again.

Can someone please help me out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use fragments. Checkout http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html 
If you have specific queries on use of fragments, would love to help.

Comment: Also further useful for you scenario would be http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I need them to be activities, not fragments.
I tried using viewpager, but its only for views. I need them to be activities. I don't think we can add activities under viewpager.

Comment: Any specific reason why you need them to be activities?

Comment: But I don't think launchers use fragments for it. Launchers have been around since before fragments were introduced.

Comment: Sure, regardless of that since fragments *are* available now, I think you should take advantage of them and use them instead of Activities unless use of an Activity in particular is needed.